# Populating a dropdown from ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewdata

I have viewdata in my controller which is populated by a list:

```
List<employee> tempEmpList = new List<employee>();
tempEmpList = context.employees.ToList();
ViewData["tempEmpList"] = tempEmpList;
```

and I am passing this into my view, the question is, how do I place the content of the viewdata list into a dropdown list?

The display data will be `.name` from the list item.

I know I could do a `foreach` on the Viewdata and create a select list, but this seems a bit long winded

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.108%29) html helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmployee", 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["tempEmpList"]), "Id", "Name")
```

In the `SelectList` constructor, you can specify which properties of the `Employee` class should be used as both the text and the value within the dropdown (e.g. "Id", "Name")

The name of the dropdown (`"SelectedEmployee"`) will be used when you post back your data to the server.

Comment: This brings up the error: ` CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments` I do like this approach though

Comment: I think you have reference `System.Collections.Generic` in your view but `SelectList` requires `System.Collections.IEnumerable` try it with the explicit namespace : `new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["tempEmpList"], "Id", "Name")`

Comment: I worked it out, had to reference the list<modeltype> and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 11):

Set up your `ViewData` in the normal way, assigning a Key name that maps to a property in your model that will be bound on `Post` ...

```
ViewData["ModelPropertyName"] = new SelectList(...)
```

Then in your view simply add a `Html.DropDownList` ...

```
@Html.DropDownList("ModelPropertyName")
```

Comment: I'm working through old code and was so confused as to how the data for a drop down was being bound, but it does seem like if the ViewData key name is the same as the DropDownList name it'll bind automatically. This helped confirm that for me. It's confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Please try with that. I have tried with MVC5

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmployee", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["tempEmpList"],"id","Name"))`