# Applying Bootstrap styling to MVC dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, bootstrapping

I am trying to apply styling to the following line

```
@Html.DropDownList("productOptions", "Products")
```

I rewrote to the following

```
@Html.DropDownList("productOptions", "Products",  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In my controller I added `productOptions` to `ViewData["productOptions"]` and *Products* is an optional string for default text

but I keep getting the following error message about the syntax

```
Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'  

Cannot resolve method 'Dropdownlist(string, string, { class:string}' candidates are:
```

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a dropdown from ViewData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090937/populating-a-dropdown-from-viewdata)

Answer (score 0):

`"Products"` needs to be the actual object not a string.

Example usage:

```
public class ExampleClass //This is the model class
{
    public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
    public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
}
//The above class you define it this way in your view
@model ExampleClass

//And you use it like this.
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProvider, Model.Providers, new { @class = "form-control" })

//In your case you have your data in ViewData
@Html.DropDownList("Products", 
new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["productOptions"], "Id", "Name"))
```

For more information look here: [Populating a dropdown from ViewData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090937/populating-a-dropdown-from-viewdata)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
List<Product> tempProduct = new List<Product>();
tempProduct = context.Products.ToList();
ViewData["tempProduct"] = tempProduct ;

@Html.DropDownList("Select Product",  new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["tempProduct"], "Id", "Name" , new { @class = "form-control" }))
```