# How can i get a dropdownbox working with a css class?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I have a `SelectList` in the controller that its value passed to the view by `ViewData` to the view as below:

```
List<string> available = new List<string>();
            available.AddRange(product.AvailableSizes.Split(',').ToList());
            ViewData["availablesize"] = new SelectList(available);
```

in the view i have a drop down box which display the values of the variable `availablesize` as below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("availablesize")
```

for some reasons i need to display this drop down box in the following format but unable to handle this issue any suggestion?

```
<div class="product-page-options">
<div class="pull-left">
<label class="control-label">Size:</label>
<select class="form-control input-sm">
 <option>L</option>
 <option>M</option>
 <option>XL</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Wanna pass the dropdown box into those divs having different css classes for styling the dropdownbox @Reddy

Comment: Are you trying to clone the dropdown and create multiple instances of the same element?

Comment: Unable to understand your issue. Can you give an example or elaborate more?

Comment: @Reddy my bad, now question is edited please have a look

Comment: @SometimesCode question is updated please have a look

Comment: Not clear what you are asking: do you want to style each option differently in the dropdownlist? For example, each option has its own color?

Comment: You can't do that just by using @Html.DropDownList. Your best bet is creating a Custom helper method in the View where you can pass the dropdownlist and it renders the resulted html. `@helper renderDropDown(SelectList items) {Your html with your dropdown}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code must work, you can give css attributes as well in the razor syntax.

Also Make sure your `ViewData["availablesize"]` has `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Change your controller code to below

```
ViewData["availablesize"] = new SelectList((IEnumerable)available);
```

in Views syntax must be like below

```
<div class="product-page-options">
 <div class="pull-left">
 <label class="control-label">Size:</label>      
    @Html.DropDownList("availablesize", ViewData["availablesize"], new {@class = "form-control input-sm "})
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the syntax that you require
[image]

Comment: doesn't work, gives an error has some invalid arguments.

Comment: that means you are not providing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your  `ViewData["availablesize"]` .. you must change your controller logic to fill the ViewData with this datatype

Comment: @NaserDostdar updated my answer, also look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091082/2592042 this might be helpful

Comment: I Still get this error
CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Ozhay.Domain.Entities.Product>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, object)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style each option differently, depending on the values passed, you can use some JQuery for that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#availablesize option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      switch ($(this).val()) {
       case 'S':
         $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
          break;
        case 'M':
         $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
          break;
        case 'L':
         $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
          break;
        case 'XL':
         $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
          break;
        default:
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="availablesize">
  <option value="">- select size -</option>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
  <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obba9daq/)

Comment: don't wanna style each option i just want to pass drop down box values into a specific format that is in my question

Comment: You mean the specific HTML format? With those exact divs and other elements?