# ASP Core MVC Scaffolding SelectList (RC1) not populating data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have three asp mvc model

**Unit**
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(25)]
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
**Bank**

```
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BankId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
   public string BankName { get; set; }
```

**BankAccount**

```
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BankId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
```

**BankAccountsController**

```
// GET: BankAccounts/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["BankId"] = new SelectList(_context.Bank, "BankId", "Bank");
        ViewData["UnitId"] = new SelectList(_context.Unit, "UnitId", "Unit");
        return View();
    }
```

**In Create View VS 2015 Scaffolding Code **

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UnitId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="UnitId" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BankId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="BankId" class ="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dropdown List is empty How I can solve it?

Comment: This question might have answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12091082/2270340. You are not associating the `ViewData` with `select`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a dropdown from ViewData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090937/populating-a-dropdown-from-viewdata)

Comment: Please use [ViewModels](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3), is so much cleaner and easier to debug code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the association between the ViewData and the select list is missing.

As can be seen [here](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx), I think you need to use `asp-items` to bind the `ViewData` with the `select` list.

```
<select asp-for="UnitId" class="form-control" asp-items="HereGoesViewDataOrViewBagForUnits"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller New Code

```
//ViewData["BankId"] = new SelectList(_context.Bank, "BankId", "Bank");
//ViewData["UnitId"] = new SelectList(_context.Unit, "UnitId", "Unit");
ViewData["BankId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Bank>(), "BankId", "BankName");
ViewData["UnitId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Unit>(), "UnitId", "UnitName");
```

**New View Code**

```
<select class="form-control"
                    asp-for="UnitId"
                    asp-items="ViewBag.UnitId"></select>
<select class ="form-control" 
                    asp-for="BankId" 
                    asp-items="ViewBag.BankId"></select>
```